# Some plotmarkers appear to be cut off in Mathematica 13.2.0 and 13.2.1 but look ok in Mathematica 11.0

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

We have noticed that some of the plotmarkers in a listplot get cut off.
We are using the below global setting to render plots with the same size as they were in Mathematica 11.0. Images appeared much larger in Mathematica 13.2 without this setting.

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "ScreenResolutionCompatibilityMode"] = True
```

Here's an example of a ListPlot with Plotmarkers

```
     ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
     PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{EdgeForm[], Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 10], 
       Graphics[], 
       Graphics[{EdgeForm[], Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}]}, 
        ImageSize -> 10], 
       Graphics[{EdgeForm[], 
         Rotate[Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}], 180 Degree]}, 
        ImageSize -> 10]}]
```

Screenshot:
[PlotMarkers Cut Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPwBz.png)

Here's another example:

```
 ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Large}] (*Plotmarkers are getting cut off*)
```

Screenshot:
[Plotmarkers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm5af.png)

I have already tried adding ImagePadding-> 1 as suggested here plotting - Custom PlotMarkers with Graphics get cut - Mathematica Stack Exchange but that makes the plotmarkers appear small so that may not be the best solution for us.
Please advise if there are any alternatives way to fix this.

Comment: Hi, I am having a similar problem, but, in my case, `ImagePadding -> 1` solved the issue. I used: `PlotMarkers -> 
 Graphics[{Black, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 11, ImagePadding -> 1]`